# Converting the value of a Column in R

Tags: r

I am using a dataset that has a column called Click, and I want to convert this column to have the value of 1 if there is at least 1 click, and 0 if there are no clicks at all. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be avoiding copying the whole vector and assign by reference only to the relevant values. You can achieve this using `data.table`, for example

```
df <- data.frame(Click = c(0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0)) # Your imaginary data

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Click > 1L, Click := 1L][]
#    Click
# 1:     0
# 2:     1
# 3:     1
# 4:     1
# 5:     0
# 6:     0
```

For a big data set you can try binary search on a keyed data set

```
setkey(df, Click)[!.(0), Click := 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset$Click <- as.numeric(dataset$Click != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work: Simply create a Boolean vector of TRUE/FALSE statements, and multiply them by one in order to get 1s or 0s.

```
k = c(5,0,6,9,3,0,0,4,5)
answer = (k > 0)*1
> k = c(5,0,6,9,3,0,0,4,5)
> answer = (k > 0)*1
> answer
[1] 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

In your case:

```
b = (dataset$Click > 0) * 1
newdataset = cbind(dataset,b)
```